# Transfer request to MVC controller or View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an http handler which picks up all requests for my custom extension .page . This works fine with old fashion asp.net where I simply do a Server.Transfer to the aspx file of choice. 
However, I would like to move this to MVC and instead reroute to either a Controller or a View. Doesn't matter which though I would prefer to a Controller.

Any help on this subject is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about adding a new entry in the `RouteTable.Routes` ignored routes:

```
routes.Ignore("{*allcustomextension}",
                new {
                    allcustomextension = @".*\.ext(/.*)?"
                });
```

This will allow the `handler` to be invoked as a physical resource.

To redirect from the handler context to a `View` use:

```
System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action("ViewName", "ControllerName");
```

Comment: but how dow I redirect/transfer from my handöer to my controller or view?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should redirect only to a controller which will select the view to render but think that you don't need that custom handler. Try something like that (you should change it somehow to match the url format you have)

```
routes.MapRoute("page", "{controller}/{action}.page");
```

If that doesn't work and you really want to redirect from your handler, combine the ignoring route from Xander with

```
Response.Redirect(System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"));
```

Afaik, Server.Transfer works only with asp.net classic so your only option is a redirect.